# Assist in modeling parking space propability in 2 parking lots

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, self-learning, mathematical-modeling, queueing-theory

i wanted to ask in assistance on modeling a problem we want to solve.
We would like to calculate the probability of finding a free parking space in 2 parking lots given that:

1. we have online real value of free parking spaces in **both** parking lots (can't get each separately) - it's not 100% accurate but its not bad. - of course if we have more than X slots available, we can consider the probability to be 100% or close to 100%.
2. we know the difficult hours (that usually the parking lot is full) - this should look like a bell (around 10:00 AM its very likely that the parking lots will be full, so manual updated - see later - should be more reliable)
3. we know the rate of people getting in and leaving the parking lot (after not finding a parking space) - there's also a probability that someone entered, and another one exited - we can't know that for sure (lets say we have 6 free parking spaces. in 11:35 - its 5 (someone entered), in 11:37 it back to 6 (someone didn't find a parking), etc...
   The rate is usually relevant to **parking lot A**, because Parking lot B's barrier will not be opened if the parking lot is full (of course if someone else which is not registered parked, the barrier will open). (so we can guess those people came in, didn't find anything, and left the parking lot)
4. manual updates - someone enters the parking lot and can update if he sees enough parking or not (seperated into A and B parking lots) - the updates are relevant mostly when they are closed to "Now" (meaning, if i see update 20 minutes ago, i should consider it less than update from 3 minutes ago).

i can try to model it with weights for each parameter - the weights should change dynamically depending on the current inputs (for example, manual update of "full" in parking A will probably receive weight of 0 when the hour is 21:00 at night), etc...

but! as i'm not mathematician, i'd love to consult with you what's the best approach to model it?

thanks

Comment: i would play with a couple of distributions in modeling software like Arena, or write a naive simulator in Excel assuming some sort of distribution of incoming and outgoing rates at different times in the day, and try to design the policies optimally -- and then the probability will be empiric from simulations, which could be repeated often if automated enough to fit changing market conditions.

Comment: @gt6989b i'm not sure i quite understand, i can do some kind of distribution, but which formula direction should i use?

Comment: not sure what you are asking. Try to model the distribution of the incoming flow of cars, using say, exponential distribution, where you will change the parameter hourly to fit the actual numerical observations over a couple of days. This gives you an idea how your incoming and outgoing flow will look. then simulate on computer what happens to your parking capacity

Comment: if you run 10,000 of such simulations, you will have a reasonably clear idea what happens on average and compute your probability that wya

Comment: we don't have time for 10,000 simulations :) we'd like to develop the tool with our current knowledge that i said above.. i'll try to find a mathematical formula i guess

Comment: running 10k simulations like this in excel should take under 10 seconds.